# calling google maps and bmap script and adding functionality

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to call the google map api with get script, then follow by calling the bmap script also with getscript, and then add in the bmap functions into that same script.  This is how I was trying to call the google map api and bmapsc

```
$.getScript("http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?    
file=api&v=2&async=2&callback=placeMap&key=my_API_key");
$.getScript("http://www.klossal.com/js/bmap/jQuery.bMap.1.3.js");
$("#map").bMap({
    mapZoom: 11,
    mapCenter:[51.501690392607,-0.1263427734375],
    mapSidebar:"sideBar", //id of the div to use as the sidebar
    markers:{"data":[
        {

"lat":51.49757618329838,"lng":-0.1746654510498047,"title":"Science  
Museum","body":"Exhibition Road, London SW7"
        },{

 "lat":51.47769451182406,"lng":-0.0009441375732421875,"title":"Royal Observatory 
Greenwich","body":"Blackheath Ave, Greenwich, London SE10"
        },{

"lat":51.49624032118747,"lng":-0.10857582092285156,"title":"Imperial War 
Museum","body":"Lambeth, London, SE1"
        },{

"lat":51.51792987720294,"lng":-0.1272869110107422,"title":"British Museum"                  
        },{

"lat":51.495625811469374,"lng":-0.17642498016357422,"title":"Natural History 
Museum","body":"Cromwell Road, London, SW7"                 
        },{

"lat":51.50177053585362,"lng":-0.12908935546875,"title":"Churchill Museum"                  
        }
    ]}
});
});
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working, any help on this would be great.

Comment: Any errors on the console we should be aware of ?

Comment: When I load the scripts with out jquery the page displays fine, some how something I'm doing with the jquery breaks it.

Comment: http://www.klossal.com/media/map.html runs fine here, but in a different site I'm using I can't run it this way.

Comment: Could you provide a link to that other site ? so I can take a look there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the link to google maps API you are using in getScript is wrong isn't it ? shouldn't it be

> http://maps.google.co.uk/maps/api/js?sensor=false

instead of

```
$.getScript("http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?file=api&v=2&async=2&callback=placeMap&key=my_API_key");
```

You don't need the get to make it work anymore, only if you want to monitor the map usage [you can see that here](https://developers.google.com/maps/signup):

> Google Maps JavaScript API v3
>
> The Google Maps JavaScript API v3 does not require an API key to
>   function correctly. However, we strongly encourage you to load the
>   Maps API using an APIs Console key which allows you to monitor your
>   application's Maps API usage. Learn how to use an APIs Console key.

Here is a way to do it:

***Warning UGLY code, just for answering pursoses please use Require.js or something similar to do loading like this on production environment***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.getScript("http://maps.google.co.uk/maps/api/js?sensor=false",
            $.getScript("http://www.klossal.com/js/bmap/jQuery.bMap.1.3.js",
                function(){
                    $("#map").bMap({
                        mapZoom: 11,
                        mapCenter:[51.501690392607,-0.1263427734375],
                        mapSidebar:"sideBar", //id of the div to use as the sidebar
                        markers:{"data":[
                            {
                                "lat":51.49757618329838,"lng":-0.1746654510498047,"title":"Science Museum","body":"Exhibition Road, London SW7"
                            },{
                                "lat":51.47769451182406,"lng":-0.0009441375732421875,"title":"Royal Observatory Greenwich","body":"Blackheath Ave, Greenwich, London SE10"
                            },{
                                "lat":51.49624032118747,"lng":-0.10857582092285156,"title":"Imperial War Museum","body":"Lambeth, London, SE1"
                            },{
                                "lat":51.51792987720294,"lng":-0.1272869110107422,"title":"British Museum"                  
                            },{
                                "lat":51.495625811469374,"lng":-0.17642498016357422,"title":"Natural History Museum","body":"Cromwell Road, London, SW7"                    
                            },{
                                "lat":51.50177053585362,"lng":-0.12908935546875,"title":"Churchill Museum"                  
                            }
                        ]}
                    });
                }));
    });
```

this callback should have your code, so it runs after both bMap and googleMaps are loaded, this is because ajax is async so it request the script to google and then the application go on.

Comment: hmm, where does the api key go?

Comment: I had looked also at this, but could figure out how to incorporate the key with this either http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE

Comment: Updated my answer to add an explanation to that.

Comment: can you do me a huge favor and look at the update source of this page and see if you see anything that looks wrong, I updated it to fit this and to be closer to the working page and still nothing.  This is the not working page http://www.klossal.com/brigham_map.html and this is teh working one http://www.klossal.com/media/map.html

Comment: Looks like your script is running before googlemaps API is loaded there for you get a Undefined error. You need to use getScript with a call back that will wait until the scripts are loaded to start running your code.

Comment: I hate to ask this, but do you know how to do that?

Comment: sigh, still just a blank page, made the changes, I'm at a loss for what to do http://www.klossal.com/brigham_map.html  I really appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Comment: so it works if I have <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>  but I'm not going to be able to enter it that way, I even changed the link in your code to match that and that still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry but I think you cannot add google maps using $.getScript(), you could try something like this then, https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async